# How to create CSS grid with auto-fill, minmax col width, and left-aligned columns?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a CSS grid with the following properties:

- The grid has a width of 100%
- The column's width should be 330px, but should shrink if this allows fitting one more column, but it should never shrink below 288px.
- All columns should have the same width
- If there is space left, left-align the columns (all remaining space should be on the right side of the grid)

Here a few examples of what I'm trying to achieve

```
Grid width => columns (width)
----------------------------

658px => |329px|329px|
         |329px|

660px => |330px|330px|
         |330px|

665px => |330px|330px|5px(whitespace)|
         |330px|

863px => |330px|330px|203px(whitespace)|
         |330px|

864px => |288px|288px|288px|

867px => |289px|289px|289px|

960px => |320px|320px|320px|
```

I've tried the following three options:

**Approach 1**

```
.grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(288px, 1fr));
}
```

The problem: The columns shrink down to 288px, but they can grow larger than 330px [Image with columns larger than the max width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnW5K.png)

**Approach 2**

```
.grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(288px, 330px));
}
```

The problem: the columns never grow, and the columns are left-aligned, but they are always 330px and never shrink down to 288px. [Image with columns that don't shrink below the max width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzITY.png)

**Approach 3**

```
.grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(288px, 1fr));
}
.grid > div {
  max-width: 330px;
}
```

The problem: The columns shrink down to 288px, and they never grow larger than 330px, but they are not left-aligned. [Image with columns that grow and shrink within boundaries, but are not left-aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX31Z.png)

As you can see, none of the approaches I've tried worked so far. All of them have different problem :( Is there any way to make this layout work with CSS Grid?

Comment: there seems to be a lot of conflicted constrains on what you want to achieve, **repeat(auto-fill, minmax(288px, 330px));** This pretty much meets the three constrains you mentioned above but then you say it's not what you wanted because of something else, I suggest you revise your question.

Comment: @ZohirSalak minmax() will always default to max so minmax(288px,330px) is simply 330px

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, but the op didn't mention shrinking behavior in one of the constrains, besides when the grid becomes one column `minmax(288px, 330px)` does what it supposed to do, I feel like The question isn't clear on the end result

Comment: @ZohirSalak *each column should have a min-size of 288px and a max size of 330px* --> so the width is within the range 288px and 330px. The question stop and the 4 first lines, everything else is what the OP tried

Comment: Hi, apologies if the question wasn't clear enough. My goal is to have as many columns as can fit on the screen with a min-width of 288px. Columns should never shrink below 288px and never grow beyond 330px. Columns should only shrink below 330px when it allows displaying an additional column. Because of these constraints, there might be white space. It should always be on the right of all grid (meaning there should be no space between them). As shown above `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(288px, 330px));` does not work. The columns never shrink below 330px. I'll update the question with this info.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, placing it only on the `.wrapper` - note I did force and exception on a column (`.three`) to show the effect of that.  I used smaller values to accommodate this results execution window

```css
.my-container {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid green 1px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.wrapper {
  border: solid cyan 1px;
  padding: 3px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(100px, 150px), 1fr));
  gap: 0.25rem;
}

.thing {
  border: solid 1px magenta;
}

.three {
  width: 40px;/* to show test of this */
  border: solid lime 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thing one">One comes before two but is a lonely number</div>
    <div class="thing two">Two burgers are more than one burger</div>
    <div class="thing three">Three</div>
    <div class="thing four">Four is the next block of super interesting content with more very happy text.</div>
    <div class="thing five">Five test of the test</div>
    <div class="thing six">Six</div>
    <div class="thing seven">Seven</div>
    <div class="thing ">Eight</div>
    <div class="thing ">More</div>
    <div class="thing ">And More</div>
    <div class="thing ">More so more</div>
    <div class="thing ">More again</div>
  </div>
</div>
```